# Is there a way which I can add meta tags / keywords to an image using Python?

Tags: python, metadata, piexif

I have been searching for hours for the ability to edit / add tags or basically keywords of/to an image via Python. I wanted to change metadata of images so I had to use Piexif library and found it completely great but there is a problem which XPKeywords requires type 'bytes' instead of 'Ascii' for some reason.

I've tried using IPTCInfo library to just edit the keywords but unfortunately didn't go out that good like I wanted to. I've also tried converting the string to bytes via 'b' prefix but still the same problem remains.

Comment: Have you made it? I'm trying to do a same thing.

Comment: @project.py yes, check my accepted answer.

Comment: Documentation say c++, not python?

Comment: I used it as a reference. Check Piexif docs, it had examples there. For adding meta tags / keywords, you will need to use `piexif.ImageIFD.XPKeywords: "keywords_here".encode('utf16'),` as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out myself by using Piexif. For anyone who has the same issue; the solution was that the meta tag was 'XPKeywords' and I had to just encode the keywords string to UCS2 (as stated here https://exiv2.org/tags.html) using 'encode' function with argument 'utf16'. The same goes to comments (meta tag: XPComment). I hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you! I came across this and it is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyExifTool](https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool).  It's a wrapper for Phil Harvey's [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and gives you a lot of control over your image's metadata.

Comment: Hello. Is there anything else?